# Android: Open Browser with Supplied Session Cookie

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm currently looking for a way to launch the default browser application on Android and pass a session cookie to it.

My application communicates with an external API over which I have no control using HttpClient, then passes the user to the site for the final stages.

I am aware that this is probably possible using a WebView, However I very specifically need to open the external browser application rather than using an internal WebView.

I know that:

```
Intent.ACTION_VIEW
```

Can be used to open the browser, however I have not managed to find much information about actually passing any additional data through.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> I'm currently looking for a way to launch the default browser application on Android and pass a session
>   cookie to it.

This is not possible, sorry.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the system or browser CookieStore and add my cookie manually to that?

Comment: @XenoPhoenix: No. That would be a major privacy violation. Not to mention the fact that the user may not be using the browser you're thinking of, anyway.

Comment: To be honest I suspected as much which was why I was hoping there was a way to do it with an intent. Though as I suspected and you answered this is unfortunately currently not supported.

Comment: @CommonsWare Is this still not possible?  Or is there another means of starting authentication with a cloud server and then passing them over to a valid browser window with their authentication key? The WebView seems as though it is quite limiting with respect to functional web page interactions. Perhaps I am missing an obvious approach.

Comment: @JaySnayder: There are dozens of Web browsers for Android. I am not aware of any that support what you are seeking, with the possible exception of Chrome, and then only if you use Chrome Custom Tabs instead of `WebView`. I'm not 100% certain that Custom Tabs covers this scenario, though I think that it does. Note that this will only work on Chrome-equipped devices, which may limit your distribution options (e.g., only to apps on the Play Store).

Comment: @CommonsWare Ok, thanks for the input. It really seems for me to just be a temporary solution until the webpage that we are using becomes public instead of handing out a set of credentials for each person in the beta to login with.  So in my particular case, its provide them with a limited `WebView` interaction using the SDK as a login within the app, or ask them to login with a default account we share to them; thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Do you know url-rewrite? It will help you achieve your demand. A url-write may be like this:
"http://localhost:8080/test/error.jsp;jsessionid=C4E6732EBB4C17F409AB41143735C096".

The "jsessionid" is the key for sessionid, and C4E6732EBB4C17F409AB41143735C096 is the value. The key to represent the sessionid attribute is different depends on what language is used in the web projects.

So, if you want to keep the session, you can launch the default like this:

```
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://localhost:8080/test/error.jsp;jsessionid=C4E6732EBB4C17F409AB41143735C096");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
```

the sessionid you can get from the HttpClient, and just add it behind your url.

There are also some problems that need to pay attention. First, in the url, the separator is ";" not "?", because the sessionid is in http header, not the http body. Second, if the browser already has a session with the server, then the url-rewrite won't work because the browser will use the its own session, to solve this, you can use you app to get the browser's session and use this session in the HttpClient.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, unfortunately this was not the cookie that I need to pass, and I had no control over the website I was passing the user to to add functionality such as this. This is potentially a good work-around for other cases however, as a strict answer to the question, CommonsWare is correct.

Comment: Also, take into consideration that URL rewrite is considered as a less secure way to support cookie based sessions. Therefore, make a minded decision if to allow it on your server.